# Who are the parents of Diedrich Peron, born about 1803 in France

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, new-york-state, france

Diedrich was born in France in about 1803 and his wife Regina was born in Württemberg, Germany in about 1812. Dedrick and Regina met and fell in love but strong opposition to their courtship was voiced by parents over differences of religion, in fact they had been forbidden to marry. Dedrick’s parents owned vineyards and while he was on a business trip, he and Regina ran away and were married. They ended up in America living in the state of New York.
Dedrick died in October of 1859 of a liver ailment. He had been ill for only three days prior to his death.

Because they eloped we have no information on Diedrich or Regina's families prior to their marriages.  Several years ago my uncle hired a professional and he couldn't find anything.  The name Diedrich is not passed down, the names of their children are often English.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format, which is different to bulletin boards, discussion forum and other Q&A sites.  Would you be able to edit your question to include the results of any searching that you have done for an immigration record of Diedrich to the US, please?  Also, what is the earliest record that you have for him/them in the US?

Comment: The story of how Diedrich and Regina fell in love and married seems to been handed down and not (yet) documented. Could they have met in America? Do you know their immigration dates? Diedrich is a German given name - could he have been German or Alsatian? The surname Peron (although rare) does appear in today's German phonebooks and in old records in Hessen. Do you have any clues as to Regina's maiden name?